# Extension Manager error in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am getting this error when I try to open the Extension Manager from VS2010 Ultimate:

The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name  Microsoft Visual Studiomust be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

I had used the reset previously to correct it:

1. Reset the skipped packages: From an elevated command-line prompt, run "devenv /ResetSkipPkgs" from under "\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE"

This no longer works for me. I also tried:

2. Revert back to the general settings: From the Tools menu, go to "Import and Export Settings". Select "Reset settings". Make sure to backup your current settings if you have done any customization. Select "General Settings". Finish the wizard and see if the problem is resolved.

I cannot open my Extension Manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this happened after installing an extension, try renaming your extensions directory (after exiting VS).  It is located at:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions
```