# Cannot use Extension Manager in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

When I try to open Extension Manager I get this error message;
"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

I have not done anything unusual, so why has this come up?

I understand I should be looking for files with long names in 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions 
but I have not located one yet that is longer than 248 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same question at StackOverFlow
[Extension Manager error in VS2010? Please Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074376/extension-manager-error-in-vs2010-please-help)

Path to extensions is %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions

Comment: I found that the pathname is different to the one you give. I changed the names of Extensions to Extension and that seemed to fix the problem, although I have to admit I do not really understand why this is and what the implications of that are.